# Vlookups in SQL

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2012, vlookup, self-join

I am attempting to write a Query that will pull in a description for each Segment of an account code. The table looks like :

[image: Current Table]

What I am wanting to do is have each CTRC section to pull in the CTDESC for the CTACCT that matches Example:

[image: Results I want]

My original data has over 4 million rows so i cannot export to excel in order to do a normal Vlookup. I only have one table with all of this data and have not been able to get self join to be able to pull in all rows I can only do it one section at a time.

```
SELECT TOP 10
       RTRIM(a.CTACCT) AS [CTACCT],
       RTRIM(a.CTRC01) AS [CTRC01],
       NULLIF(CONCAT(RTRIM(a.CTrc01), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc02)), CONCAT(RTRIM(a.CTrc01), '-')) AS [CTRC02],
       NULLIF(CONCAT(RTRIM(a.CTrc01), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc02), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc03)), CONCAT(RTRIM(a.CTrc01), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc02), '-')) AS [CTRC03],
       NULLIF(CONCAT(RTRIM(a.CTrc01), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc02), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc03), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc04)), CONCAT(RTRIM(a.CTrc01), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc02), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc03), '-')) AS [CTRC04],
       NULLIF(CONCAT(RTRIM(a.CTrc01), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc02), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc03), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc04), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc05)), CONCAT(RTRIM(a.CTrc01), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc02), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc03), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc04), '-')) AS [CTRC05],
       NULLIF(CONCAT(RTRIM(a.CTrc01), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc02), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc03), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc04), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc05), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc06)), CONCAT(RTRIM(a.CTrc01), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc02), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc03), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc04), '-', RTRIM(a.CTrc05), '-')) AS [CTRC06],
       a.CTDESC AS [CTDESC],
       a.CTSEGN AS [CTSEGN]
FROM [PSA].[dbo].[SMFD35_GLDBFA_GLPCT] a WITH (NOLOCK);
```

I am using SQL Server.

---

Comment: A "`VLookup`" in SQL is called a `JOIN`. Also, why use `NOLOCK` here? Do you understand the implications of it's use is?

Comment: You edited codeblocked tables in exchange for pictures.  This is a step backwards.

Comment: Images of data and results are nearly worthless. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I have tried using a join but can only get it to successfully pull in one of the additional rows if I try to get it to pull in the second I get no results. Also my company requires the no lock.      
  FROM [PSA].[dbo].[SMFD35_GLDBFA_GLPCT] a with (nolock)
  Inner Join [PSA].[dbo].[SMFD35_GLDBFA_GLPCT] d 
  on rtrim(d.CTRC01) = rtrim(a.CTACCT)
  
  Inner Join [PSA].[dbo].[SMFD35_GLDBFA_GLPCT] e 
  on rtrim(e.CTRC02) = rtrim(a.CTACCT)    These were the Joins I used.

Comment: *"Also my company requires the no lock as multiple people can be pulling from the data"* Sounds like your company needs to actually implement some indexes and stop telling people that they should be "ok" with wrong results.

Comment: Eek. I understand about a lot of people. But NOLOCK is NOT a magical go faster button. It does fun things like return missing and/or duplicate rows randomly so you can't reproduce the error. The other thing that jumps out here is the table seems to have some normalization issues. When you have things like CTrc01, CTrc02 you have what is known as repeating groups. And it violates 1NF.

Comment: What if you combined all of the CTRC values into one column using a union query, then joined to the lookup table from that? (eg. Row: 1, ColumnName: CTRC01, Value: 001; etc.). Might be best to materialize it in a table, first, so it can be indexed.

Comment: @JJ32 the CTACCT column is a union of all the CTRC Columns. I have to get a description for each step of the account which is what the CTRC columns are showing. I am trying to get a query to compare the CTRC columns to the matching CTACCT column and pull in the CTDESC column . So if the account is 001-0000-000-1010 then it would need to look up 001, then 001-0000, then 001-0000-000, then 001-0000-000-1010.

Comment: All the `RTRIM`s are pretty odd too; why would all those columns have whitespace at the end?

Comment: @Larnu I do not know why. I did not create the table. I just know they do and that this is the only way I can get the query to pull in those sections accurately. The current Query is working accuratly to pull in the data for the first step. I just need help creating the joins in order to create the additional Description columns to pull in the description field of the CTACCT that matches each CTRC column.

Comment: I see. Is each segment of the account stored as a whole, eg. is the value of CTRC-002 in the PSA].[dbo].[SMFD35_GLDBFA_GLPCT table '0000' or '001-0000' (I assume the former)

Comment: @JJ32 The CTRC02 Column on its own would pull in 0000 in your example above. The is why i have the Concats on the query to combine them to show the full string to that point.

Comment: Ok great.  Final question, what version of SQL Server are you using?  As it will make life much simpler if it is 2016-plus (also please tag the question).

Comment: @JJ32 I am using SQL Server 2012 but also have access to Power BI Report Builder. I can use either to create this query which ever works better.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple ways to do this, since you already have the values in your tables one approach would be to add an id field from the original table and tag which CTRC (LevelNr) corresponds to the CTACCT in the results:

```
select A.CTACCT, max(B.CTRC01) AS CTRC01, 
  max(case when B.LevelNr = 1 then B.Description else null end) AS CTRC01_Description,
  max(case when A.LevelNr >=2 then B.CTRC02 else null end) AS CTRC02, 
  max(case when A.LevelNr >=2 and B.LevelNr = 2 then B.Description else null end) AS CTRC02_Description,
  max(case when A.LevelNr >=3 then B.CTRC03 else null end) AS CTRC03, 
  max(case when A.LevelNr >=3 and B.LevelNr = 3 then B.Description else null end) AS CTRC03_Description
from @MyResults A
  inner join @MyResults B on A.id = B.id
group by A.[CTACCT], A.id, A.LevelNr
order by A.[CTACCT], A.id, A.LevelNr
```

Results:

```
CT_ACCT        CTRC01 CTRC01_Description CTRC02   CTRC02_Description CTRC03        CTRC03_Description
001            001    Company            NULL     NULL               NULL          NULL
001-0000       001    Company            001-0000 Department         NULL          NULL
001-0000-0000  001    Company            001-0000 Department         001-0000-0000 Location
```

This should really be a discussion about database design, though.  If you have data that stores each CTRC value separately that's where grouping functions like STRING_AGG() and PIVOT come into play.

Assuming you can get your data in a state like below using UNION queries:

```
id RowNr CTAcct
1  1     001
1  2     0000
1  3     0000
2  1     002
2  2     0000
2  3     0000
```

You can then get all your account numbers and descriptions together as below (STRING_AGG is nicer, but FOR XML will do the trick for your version):

```
select [CTACCT], id, RowNr, Description
from
(
select RowNr, id,
  STUFF((SELECT '-' + [CTACCT]
    from @CTACCTS A where A.[id] = T.[id] and A.[RowNr] <= T.[RowNr]
    FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1,'') as [CTACCT]
from @CTACCTS T
) A left join @CTDESCRIPTIONS D ON A.[CTACCT] = D.[CTACCT]
```

Results:

```
CTACCT        id RowNr Description
001           1  1     Company
001-0000      1  2     Department
001-0000-0000 1  3     Location
```

Finally you can then do something similar to the above to group things back together.  This may seem like extra work but has the advantage of avoiding redundancy.

Of course, you could also do a series of update statements, but generally non-set based routines aren't recommended in SQL Server.